# Something wrong with System command

Tags: command, system

First of all thanks a lot for reading this post and being able to help.
I have a problem whit System command.

if I write:

```
sprintf(command, "%s %0.0f %0.0f 0 %0.0f %0.0f %s 0 0 +", princi,wps.front().x(), wps.front().y(),wps.back().x(),wps.back().y(),name_bmp);

chdir("/home/"); //To change directory
system(command);
```

It give me segmentation fault when it runs system(command)

However if I write:

```
system("./princi 0 747.37 427.68 0 844.37 42.54 prueba_princi.bmp 0 0 +")
```

it runs perfectly....

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked that your command string is well formed or any of the variables of your sprintf command?

Comment: Yes... string is okey...

Comment: I doubt that system command is seg faulting.. It should be sprintf command. Can you paste the backtrace ?